# Rotate a Gmap marker (bitmap) by any degree in C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, gmap.net

I'm using GMaps for using google maps on c#. I write latitude and langitude values and press the load button. Then the code put a marker(like arrow) that point. I want to rotate that marker for any degree like google maps'. I don't have any sensors so I can write the degree in a textbox and press a rotate button. How can i do that? This code shows how I create markers and put them into my map. I know bitmap a little but not too much and sorry for my bad english. I hope you'll understand what I want.

```
       `double lat = Convert.ToDouble(txtLat.Text);
        double lng = Convert.ToDouble(txtLong.Text);
        map.Position = new PointLatLng(lat, lng);
        //custom marker
        Bitmap bmpMarker = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("img/arrow.png");
        PointLatLng point = new PointLatLng(lat, lng);

        GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapMarker marker = new GMarkerGoogle(point, bmpMarker);
        //1. Create a Overlay
        GMapOverlay markers = new GMapOverlay("markers");
        map.ZoomAndCenterMarkers("markers");
        //2. Add all available markers to that Overlay
        markers.Markers.Add(marker);
        //3. Cover map with Overlay
        map.Overlays.Add(markers);
        //RotateImage(bmpMarker, 180.0f);
        marker.ToolTipText = map.Position.ToString();`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the Bitmap image again with the rotation because it is not a reference type:

```
GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapMarker marker = new GMarkerGoogle(point, RotateImg(bmpMarker,45));
```

Suggestion to rotate the bitmap:

```
public Bitmap RotateImg(Bitmap bmpimage, float angle)
{
    int w = bmpimage.Width;
    int h = bmpimage.Height;
    PixelFormat pf;
    pf = bmpimage.PixelFormat;
    Bitmap tempImg = new Bitmap(w, h, pf);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tempImg);
    g.DrawImageUnscaled(bmpimage, 1, 1);
    g.Dispose();
    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
    path.AddRectangle(new RectangleF(0.0F, 0.0F, w, h));
    Matrix mtrx = new Matrix();

    mtrx.Rotate(angle);
    RectangleF rct = path.GetBounds(mtrx);
    Bitmap newImg = new Bitmap(Convert.ToInt32(rct.Width), Convert.ToInt32(rct.Height), pf);
    g = Graphics.FromImage(newImg);
    g.TranslateTransform(-rct.X, -rct.Y);
    g.RotateTransform(angle);
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
    g.DrawImageUnscaled(tempImg, 0, 0);
    g.Dispose();
    tempImg.Dispose();
    return newImg;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's working. But the marker's quality and size changed.

Comment: Try to set the Graphics instance to SmoothingMode.HighQuality. add this line of code: `g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;`